# How to create more than one .local address pointing to my mac

Tags: multicast, bonjour

I currently have one .local address (Bonjour) pointing to my mac in my intranet, mbp.local, configured in system preferences with the computer name. I use this to send my boss links to demos on my local server (he sits in a chair behind me : >).

I'd like to be able to create new .local addresses to send different demos to my boss (demo1.local, demo2.local, etc) so that I can switch to different working copies to do other work while the demos are still live.

I'd know how to setup Apache to route these requests to the right places, but am unsure if it's possible to make new addresses that point to my mac (I think this has to do with multicasting?).

I have a dynamic IP in my intranet but would be able to setup a static IP if required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about web site demos?  I'm not sure I understand the problem.  If they're web sites, I'm sure you already know you can simply use a single address with different urls, eg, http://mbp.local/demo1, http://mbp.local/demo2, etc.  If it is something else entirely, you can use the Mac's local host file to point multiple fqdns to a single IP address on your local network, but it would be best to have a static IP.  Alternatively, you could edit your DNS or WINS server to do the address translation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but I wonder if you could use what's [documented here](http://mikeferrier.ca/2011/04/04/setting-up-wildcard-dns-on-localhost-domains-on-osx/) to start. The difference would be that you'll send your boss links to http://demo1.mbp.local and so on.

I found more about this on [this thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/298004/how-do-i-use-my-localhost-dns-server-when-offline-on-snow-leopard).